# How to sort a field based on number of upvote array in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of object and there is a field which is an array and I want to sort the result based on its length.

I have tried with lodash orderBy but its showing in asc to desc instead of desc to asc.

Code -->

```
const arr = [{answer: "don't knoweee",
              questionText: "Test?" ,
              upvote:[246,22]},
             {answer: "Test2",
              questionText: "dummy question?" ,
              upvote:[246]
             },
               {answer: "answertest",
              questionText: "Hello?" ,
              upvote:null
            }]
```

My solution :

```
orderBy(arr, (i) => i?.upvote?.length, ['desc']
```

Its showing "dummy question?" first instead of "Test?" question.

Comment: But you said descending by length in your solution and what you have IS the longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const upvoteLength = ({upvote:x})=>x?.length??0;
const descending = f=>(a,b)=>f(b)-f(a);
console.log([...arr].sort(descending(upvoteLength)));
```

Comment: That doesn't always work when it's `null`

Comment: @adiga I tweaked it, please let me know if there is a test case that does not work

Comment: @AndrewParks Thanks.This is working as expected.
Can you please explain me the logic?

Comment: @AnuragSharma `[...arr]` uses the spread operator to shallow clone the array, so the original `arr` is not mutated by the sort. `{upvote:a}` uses destructuring to extract the `upvote` property of each object sorted, and aliases it to the variable `a`. The `.?length` ensures that a `null` upvote property will be treated as undefined, and then `??=0` turns any undefined values into `0` using the nullish coalescing operator. The `b-a` part generally is the standard way to do a descending sort in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration to your solution should correct this.

```js
const arr = [{
    answer: "don't knoweee",
    questionText: "Test?",
    upvote: [246, 22]
  },
  {
    answer: "Test2",
    questionText: "dummy question?",
    upvote: [246]
  },
  {
    answer: "answertest",
    questionText: "Hello?",
    upvote: null
  }
];

let newarr = _.orderBy(arr, [(i) => i.upvote?.length], ['desc']);
console.log(newarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```